# How do I prevent home folder files and folder from showing on the desktop as icons in Linux Mint 15?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I have a fresh install of Mint 15 with Cinnamon and I can't find an option to hide all icons on the desktop. In settings->Desktop there are only options to show/hide the home folder, trash, etc, but no option to hide the contents of the "Desktop" folder.

How do I hide the `$HOME` folder contents from appearing on the desktop in Linux Mint 15?

**UPDATE**:

It actually looks like the icons on the desktop are the contents of the `$HOME` folder, not `$HOME/Desktop`.

** Question was edited to reflect the fact that it was the user's home folder icons showing, not just "my computer", "trash", etc.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and the following command solved it:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.preferences desktop-is-home-dir false
```

The related issue on github is [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/382).

Comment: I think this is the real solution. +1 for the github link

Answer (score 2):

Cinnamon uses `nemo` to draw the desktop. One way of removing the icons would be to stop `nemo` from loading. Go to "Cinnamon Settings" => "Startup Programs" and deselect "Nemo" from the list of startup programs.

Alternatively, to select which icons you want to show, go to "Cinnamon Settings" => "Desktop"  (this is from my Cinnamon 1.8.2):

[image]

Comment: I've been to the desktop icons setting window before, but the problem is, it's showing all of the files and folders in my home folder (not Desktop folder) right on the desktop. Isn't nemo also the file manager? Don't I need that to browse files/folders?

Comment: @NRahl yes, `nemo` is the file manager. If you use it to browse, that will make the desktop appear (sorry, I never use the file manager, I do verything from the command line so it did not occur to me). If it showing the contents of your `$HOME`, there is something else going on, I would recommend posting a different question or editing this one to ask about that only.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the answer to this problem was discovering that somehow ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs was setting "$HOME" as the value for all the various XDG_* properties, instead of "$HOME/Desktop", "$HOME/Downloads", etc.

I created a new, fresh user and logged into Cinnamon with that user. I was able to copy that user's default ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs back to my user homedir (fixing ownership and permissions, of course), and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me in Mint 17.3 using cinnamon 2.8.6

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
```

Comment: How is this different then the existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

Cinnamon Desktop environment used to provide option to hide desktop icons, but I believe that option is no longer available since version 1.6.
If you can get to install a previous version of cinnamon you might be still able to do that

Comment: If they removed it... is there another way to do it? I don't see why they would remove a feature, unless it was replaced by something functionally equivalent.

Comment: @NRahl *Use dconf editor Go to org-gnome-desktop-background and tick "Show desktop icons"* - I picked this up from an ubuntu forum, and since I am on a windows machine right now, I can't test it.If it helps you do let me know , I will append it to my answer